# swift+loading JSON partially

Tags: json, swift, tableview

I am parsing a huge JSON response, so it takes too much time to populate my tableview. What is the proper way to display, only 30 cells first, then display other data when I push the next button, or scroll the end of the table... ?

```
func loadData(){
   let url = "api link"
   Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
      .responseJSON { response in
       guard response.result.error == nil else {                        
             print(response.result.error!)
             return
       }
       if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
          let post = JSON(value)
          if let data = post["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
            self.addressList = data
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
          }
        }
    }}
```

Comment: You can add paging parameters to your API call and also you have to customise your server code.
page:1, size:30 then get other 30 items. page:2, size:30

Comment: API development is not under my control, so this is not possible

Comment: *"it takes too much time"* – which specific operation takes too much time? Have you used the time profiler to measure?